# Difference in setting iOS camera default configuration using setExposurePointOfInterest

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, ios-camera

I am trying to set my camera exposure settings to default configuration using
`setExposurePointOfInterest:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)`
Is this different from 
`setExposurePointOfInterest:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)`

If I use the CGPoint without float, will it cause change in the auto exposure behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result here will be exactly the same.

The CGPointMake() function is declared to take CGFloat values (which are defined on 32-bit as floats and on 64-bit as doubles). If you pass in values of a different type they will be implicitly casted for you.

Since your value (.5) only requires accuracy out to a single decimal point you can safely cast it between double and float types with no information loss.

Comment: While you may be true for devices with 32 bit devices. I am not sure about the devices on 64 bit devices.Because `CGFloat` structure uses double or float based on the preprocessor macro of __LP64__